# Does grails use spring's MVC front controller or it has its open implementation?

Tags: java, spring, grails

Does grails use spring's MVC front controller or it has its open implementation?

Comment: Why would it need another implementation, given the limited purpose of a front controller?

Comment: it wouldn't, I just didn't know it was really a spring app under the covers.

Answer (score 3):

[Grails docu](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html) says that Grails is actually a Spring MVC application in disguise.

> Grails subclasses Spring's
>   DispatcherServlet and uses it to
>   delegate onto Grails controllers